# ruby on rails vs codeigniter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, codeigniter, frameworks

between ruby on rails and codeigniter, which framework is better (and why) for a website with

1. user management
2. profile pages
3. subscriptions
4. blog
5. upload/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the frameworks you mention could handle a web site with those requirements.

You should also add [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) to your list of possible choices as they too would suit your needs.

**Do you have any experience in building applications with Ruby/PHP/Python?**

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which language you favour. Pretty much any web framework could do all of those things. I'd personally favour Codeigniter, as PHP is more widely supported on hosting platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I also think both platforms are equally capable of doing the things you want. In such cases, other things become important, such as the size of the community and hosting options. In that case, PHP and CI would be a clear winner over RoR.